# How to derive these column E and F(excel) in SAS?

Tags: excel, sas

Hello i would like to derive column E and F in SAS. I have done it via Excel and this is as follows.

Column E: =IF(D2=1,1,IF(OR(C2=1,A2<>A1),"",E1))

Column F: =IF(AND(E1="",E2=1),B2,IF(AND(E2=1,E1=1),IF(B2>F1,B2,F1),""))

[image: Excel Image]

Comment: Are you looking for local maxima/minima?

Comment: In the future, please post data as text not an image. An image means we have to type out the data.

Comment: Is your new amt variable just a running max() of amt?

Answer (score 0):

SAS has by group processing which makes some of that unnecessary. I've put a solution below but it's untested since you didn't provide sample data.

Some concepts you may want to get familiar with:

- [RETAIN](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p0t2ac0tfzcgbjn112mu96hkgg9o.htm&locale=en) - holds values across the rows
- [BY/FIRST](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p0yeyftk8ftuckn1o5qzy53284gz.htm&locale=en) - allows you to
  identify the start and end of 'groups' of data
- [CALL MISSING()](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=vdmmlcdc&cdcVersion=1.0&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p1iq436yh8838rn1ud38om45n99k.htm&locale=en) - sets
  values to missing, regardless of data type (num/char)

  ```
   data want;
   set have;
   retain newflag newAmount;
   by acctNo;

   if first.acctNo or seq=1 then do;
       call missing(newFlag);
       call missing(newAmount);
   end;

   if flag=1 then newAmount = amount;

    run;
  ```

PS. sample data must be in text, not images. Also, if you had prior steps that calculated flag and sequence there are ways to do this in a single data step.